# for loop not returning what i expected

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

this is the xml document, let's call it document.xml for the sake of the example

```
<garage>
   <bike>
       <brand>Ducati</brand>
       <year>2000</year>
   </bike>
   <bike>
       <brand>Honda</brand>
       <year>2008</year>
   </bike>
   <bicycle>
       <brand>Trek</brand>
       <year>2004</year>
   </bicycle>
   <car>
       <brand>Porsche</brand>
       <year>1987</year>
   </car>
   <car>
       <brand>Volvo</brand>
       <year>2008</year>
   </car>
   <car>
       <brand>Ford</brand>
       <year>2012</year>
   </car>
</garage>
```

**I want to retrieve this, which is all the car elements**

```
      <car>
        <brand>Porsche</brand>
        <year>1987</year>
      </car>
      <car>
        <brand>Volvo</brand>
        <year>2008</year>
      </car>
      <car>
        <brand>Ford</brand>
        <year>2012</year>
      </car>
```

This is my xquery file:

```
     let $document:=doc('document.xml')

     for $car in $document/garage[descendant::car]
     return
     <car>
        <brand>{$car/brand/text()}</brand>
        <year>{$car/year/text()}</year>
     </car>
```

Instead, with this xquery file, i'm getting this:

```
    <car>
       <brand>PorscheVolvoFord</brand>
       <year>198720082012</year>
    </car>
```

Also tried this:

```
     let $document:=doc('document.xml')
     let $i:=0

     for $car in $document/garage[descendant::car]
     let $i:=$i+1
     return
     <car>
        <brand>{$car[$i]/brand/text()}</brand>
        <year>{$car[$i]/year/text()}</year>
     </car>
```

but could only retrieve the index[1]:

```
   <car>
      <brand>Porsche</brand>
      <year>1987</year>
   </car>
```

***EDIT:***

SOLVED IT! Thanks to @dirkk

What worked for me was:

```
for $car in $document/garage[descendants::car]
return $car/element()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what XQuery processor you are using, but the output you claim to get is incorrect for the given XQueries. `$car` is actually bound to a garage element, thus `$car/brand` will be an empty result. You have to do:

```
 for $car in $document/garage/car
 return
 <car>
    <brand>{$car/brand/string()}</brand>
    <year>{$car/year/string()}</year>
 </car>
```

If you want the whole `car` element, you can simply do:

```
$document/garage/car
```

Also, you should use `string()` instead of `text()`, it has several benefits (e.g. you do not get comments back, if there are any in your XML.

Comment: Thanks. $document/garage/car/element() did the trick. Never thought about it before. Thas a lot @dirkk